# React Typescript - Vertical and horizontal data in table from a single JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, logic

So, I'm getting a response from an API, resulting in an array containing multiple objects. The structure is basically:

```
data = [
    {
        month: 2,
        row1: 1,
        row2: 2,
        row3: 3
    },
    {
        month: 5,
        row1: 4,
        row2: 5,
        row3: 6
    },
    {
        month: 8,
        row1: 7,
        row2: 8,
        row3: 9
    }
]
```

These are supposed to be rendered in a calendar year table with the `row keys` as row titles, and the `values` rendered in the matching `month` cell (1-12). For example, with the above array:

```
     | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
row1 |     |  1  |     |     |  4  |     |     |  7  |     |     |     |     |
row2 |     |  2  |     |     |  5  |     |     |  8  |     |     |     |     |
row3 |     |  3  |     |     |  6  |     |     |  9  |     |     |     |     |
```

The API **only gives objects that *have* values**, so some month columns will be empty (like above). This means that I need to render an empty `<td></td>` when a month has no values. If a month **has** values, then **all rows have values too.**

How can I render a table like this in React (with Typescript)? Using npm packages is OK if needed. It does not have to be a `<table>` either, as long as I can **use it as a table** for presentation.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to reformat the data a bit and use functions to get the data which can return a fallback value if undefined.

Let's start with defining our types in typescript.  I'm assuming that `row1`, `row2`, etc. are placeholders for actual names.  So what we start out with is:

```
type RowValues = Record<string, number>;

type Raw = RowValues & { month: number };

const data: Raw[] = [/*...*/]
```

Now let's reformat it into something with just the rows keyed by month.  We know that each month either has a complete set of rows or nothing.

```
type Formatted = Record<number, RowValues | undefined>;

const formatted: Formatted = Object.fromEntries( 
  data.map( 
    ({month, ...rows}) => ([month, rows])
  )
);
```

I didn't insert actual month names but here's what I did:

```
export const Table = ({ data }: { data: Raw[] }) => {
  const formatted: Formatted = Object.fromEntries(
    data.map(({ month, ...rows }) => [month, rows])
  );

  const rowKeys = Object.keys(Object.values(formatted)[0] || {});

  const monthNos = [...new Array(12)].map((_, i) => i);

  const getValue = (month: number, row: string): string => {
    const rows = formatted[month];
    return rows ? rows[row].toString() : "";
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          {monthNos.map((i) => (
            <th scope="col">Month #{i}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rowKeys.map((key) => (
          <tr key={key}>
            <th scope="row">{key}</th>
            {monthNos.map((i) => (
              <td>{getValue(i, key)}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64454117-8kgsc?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
const Months = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar ",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec"
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          {Months.map((month) => (
            <th>{month}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
        {Object.keys(data[0]).map((key, rowIndex) => (
          <tr>
            {Months.map((m, index) => {
              const monthObject = data.find((d) => d.month === index + 1);
              return (
                <td>
                  {monthObject ? monthObject["row" + (rowIndex + 1)] : ""}
                </td>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
```

Here is a sandbox as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-platform-27khm?file=/src/App.tsx:324-1142